livewire form submit button reloads the page and appends a "?" at the end of the url
this is my livewire component named locations in the views
    <div>

    <x-slot name="title">
        {{ __('Location Management') }}

    </x-slot>


    <x-slot name="content">

           <!-- /Add modal -->

        <div wire:ignore.self class="modal fade" id="modal-add"  >
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Create New Location</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-     label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <form wire:submit.prevent="store" action="#" >
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="location_name">Location Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Location Name"
                                           wire:model="location"   id="location" required>

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="status">Select Status</label>
                                        <select class="form-control" wire:model="status"  id="status" required>
                                            <option value="Active">Active</option>
                                            <option value="Disabled">Disabled</option>
                                        </select>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" >Close</button>
                         <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary"  >Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                        
                    </form>
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>

        <!-- /.modal -->


        <!-- /edit modal -->

        <div class="modal fade" id="modal-edit">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Location</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Location Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1"
                                        placeholder="Enter Route Name">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Select Status</label>
                                    <select class="form-control">
                                        <option>Active</option>
                                        <option>Disabled</option>

                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" wire:model="isSubmitting">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>

        
        <!-- /.modal -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">



                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">


                        <div class="button-group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
                                data-target="#modal-add">Create</button>
                            <div class="float-right">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Import</button>
                                <button id="exportBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Export</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>



                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card-header -->
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="gv">
                                    <div class="table-responsive">
                                        <table id="datatable" class="grid table table-striped table-bordered"
                                            style="width:100%">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Location</th>
                                                    <th>Status</th>
                                                    <th>Created_at</th>
                                                    <th>Action</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                @foreach ($records as $record)
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>{{ $record->location_name }}</td>
                                                        <td>{{ $record->status }}</td>
                                                        <td>{{ $record->created_at }}</td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal"
                                                                data-target="#modal-edit"><i
                                                                    class="pr-2 fa fa-edit text-green"></i></a>
                                                            <a href="#" wire:click="deleteLocation({{ $record->id }})"><i class="fa fa-trash text-red"></i></a>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </tbody>
                                            <tfoot>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Location</th>
                                                    <th>Status</th>
                                                    <th>Created_at</th>
                                                    <th>Action</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tfoot>
                                        </table>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card-body -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.card -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->


   

    </x-slot>

</div>

This is my backend code
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use App\Models\Location;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Livewire\Component;

class Locations extends Component
{

    public $location_name;
    public $status;


    public $records; // Define a public property to hold the locations

    public function mount()
    {
        // Fetch locations from the database
        $this->records = Location::all();
    }


    public function store()
    {
       
        dd($this->location_name, $this->status);
        Location::create([
            'location_name' => $this->location_name,
            'status' => $this->status,
        ]);

        // Reset form fields after submission
        $this->reset(['location_name', 'status']);

        Session::flash('message', 'Data Saved Successfully');
        Session::flash('alert-class', 'alert-success');
    }


    public function deleteLocation($locationId)
    {
        // Find the location by ID
        $location = Location::findOrFail($locationId);

        // Delete the location
        $location->delete();

        // Fetch locations again after deletion
        $this->records = Location::all();

        // Optionally, you can display a success message
        session()->flash('message', 'Location deleted successfully.');
    }
    public function render()
    {

        return view('livewire.locations');
    }
    
}

and below is my controller
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use App\Models\Location;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Livewire\Component;

class Locations extends Component
{

    public $location_name;
    public $status;


    public $records; // Define a public property to hold the locations

    public function mount()
    {
        // Fetch locations from the database
        $this->records = Location::all();
    }


    public function store()
    {
       
        dd($this->location_name, $this->status);
        Location::create([
            'location_name' => $this->location_name,
            'status' => $this->status,
        ]);

        // Reset form fields after submission
        $this->reset(['location_name', 'status']);

        Session::flash('message', 'Data Saved Successfully');
        Session::flash('alert-class', 'alert-success');
    }


    public function deleteLocation($locationId)
    {
        // Find the location by ID
        $location = Location::findOrFail($locationId);

        // Delete the location
        $location->delete();

        // Fetch locations again after deletion
        $this->records = Location::all();

        // Optionally, you can display a success message
        session()->flash('message', 'Location deleted successfully.');
    }
    public function render()
    {

        return view('livewire.locations');
    }
    
}

For the past three days, I've been grappling with a persistent issue regarding form submissions in my Laravel application using Livewire. Despite extensive research and experimentation, I've been unable to achieve the desired functionality of submitting forms without triggering a page reload.
The crux of the problem lies in integrating Livewire with Bootstrap modals to create a seamless user experience. While I've successfully set up the modal and wired the form fields to Livewire properties using wire:model, every attempt to submit the form results in an undesirable page refresh.
I've explored Livewire's documentation extensively, trying various approaches such as wire:submit.prevent to intercept form submissions and prevent default behavior. While this approach prevents the page from reloading, it doesn't address the underlying issue of triggering server-side actions without disrupting the user flow.
Additionally, I've encountered challenges in orchestrating server-side actions seamlessly within Livewire components. While I understand the basic lifecycle hooks such as mount(), I struggle to execute more complex operations such as database updates or API calls without encountering unexpected behavior.
Despite my best efforts, I've hit a roadblock and am in need of guidance to overcome these challenges. I believe there may be nuances or best practices specific to Livewire that I'm overlooking, and I'm eager to learn from others' experiences and insights.
In summary, my primary goal is to enable form submissions without page reload.

Do other components/form submits work? Have you made sure livewire JS and CSS are being loaded? Have you tried removing dd($this->location_name, $this->status); from your method?

Yes i have checked in the browser debugging console under the networks tab ,i can see my livewire js being loaded and no this is the only submit am working on ,i have worked on any other submits on this project and i havent removed dd($this->location_name, $this->status); since its not even reaching the server

Alright guys i was able to find the solution after numerous tries,
The problem was in two files the app.blade which is the layout template and the locations.blade .i enclosed my location content in an <x-slot> tag with the name  content instead of just leaving it enclosed in the root div tags and secondly dont use {{$content}} in the app.blade but change it to  {{$slot}}

I'm not using x-slot, but facing pretty same issue actually. Whenever I submit the form I receive blank screen with the /? in the end of my url. If I remove $this->validation() it solves the problem. Any thoughts?
